# render and select data from mvc3 DropDown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Simple situation

One object User have many UserGroups.

I want to implement on mvc3 form editing or creating action to select UserGroups from drop down.

**Controller:**

```
private List<User> GetAllUsers()
{
    List<User> users;
    users = find all users to List...
    return users;
}

public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
   ViewBag.UserGroups = new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name");
   return View();
}
```

**View:**

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGroupId, "UserGroupId")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList(WHAT TO PUT HERE ?);
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGroupId)
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oh please use a view model, cut that crap of a ViewBag, makes me sick every time I see it.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserGroups { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid Id)
{
    var model = new UserViewModel
    {
        UserGroups = new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name")
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and in the view:

```
@model UserViewModel
...
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserGroupId, "UserGroupId")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.UserGroupId, Model.UserGroups);
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserGroupId)
    </div>
</div>
```

---

but if you wanna make me sick and keep the ViewCrap:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.UserGroupId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.UserGroups
)
```

Comment: There's no need for words like sick and crap.

Comment: Of course that there's a need. When you see questions like this coming hundreds time a day of people using ViewBag and having problems with ASP.NET MVC you eventually get sick. It's the only to cure. People are struggling like hell with ASP.NET MVC and the only reason they are struggling is because they are not using view models.

Comment: Don't answer then, it's not the OP's fault you get sick.

Comment: @Jorge, there can't be love towards ViewBag. Only hatred. There are no seasons for it. No summer, no winter. It stalks you everywhere and is ready to bite you every single time you type those keywords in your code editor. So we need to chase it and eradicate it. The sooner the better. If I had a single feature request for ASP.NET MVC 5 that would be to throw an exception from the ViewBag/ViewData getters with a juicy text.

Comment: Also, the OP's issue has nothing to do with misuse or misunderstanding of ViewBag.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am insisting on it. So that there aren't others like him. Because SO is a pretty well referenced site read by many people, no only OPs.

Answer (score 0):

On the controller:

```
ViewBag.UserGroupId = new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name");
```

On the view:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.UserGroupId, null);
```

If you want type-safety instead you can use this helper method:

```
void SetSelectList<TModel, TProperty>(
   TModel model, 
   Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> propertySelector, 
   IEnumerable<SelectListItem> list) {

   this.ViewData[ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(propertySelector)] = list;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
SetSelectList(model, m => m.UserGroupId, new SelectList(GetAllUsers(), "UserId", "Name"));
```

---

Bonus tip: Use `ToDictionary` for extra type-safety when creating the `SelectList` instance:

```
new SelectList(GetAllUsers().ToDictionary(u => u.UserId, u => u.Name), "Key", "Value")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select Multiple UserGroups for a User, you need `ListBoxFor`.

Add a string array in your ViewModel to handle the selected items and a collection property for all Groups.

```
public class UserViewModel
{
  //Other properties here
  public string[] SelectedGroups { get; set; }  
  public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> UserGroups{ get; set; }
}
```

In your `GET` action method, Get a list of UserGroups and assign to the `UserGroups` proeprty pf UserViewModel ViewModel object.

```
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var vm = new UserViewModel();
    //The below code is hardcoded for demo. you mat replace with DB data.
    vm.UserGroups= new[]
    {
      new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "Group 1" },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "Group 2" },
      new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "Group 3" }
    };  
    return View(vm);
}
```

Now in your View, Which is strongly typed to `UserViewModel` class,

```
@model UserViewModel
<h2>Create User </h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.ListBoxFor(s => s.SelectedGroups, 
                new SelectList(Model.UserGroups, "Value", "Text"))
  <input type="submit" value="Save" />
}
```

Now when user posts this form, you will get the Selected Items value in the `SelectedGroups` property of the ViewModel

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(UserViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        string[] groups= model.SelectedGroups;
        //check items now
        //do your further things and follow PRG pattern as needed
    }
    //reload the groups again in the ViewModel before returning to the View
    return View(model);
}
```