# DropDownList error: here is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key ''

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have this working in .net Fiddle, but get the error when running locally: https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Ptssq

What could cause the exact same code not to work when running locally in .net 4.5.1 mvc?

I have seen answers to similar questions that suggest to use DropDownListFor() instead but I need the capability of DropDownList that allows you to add extensions (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.selectextensions.dropdownlist.aspx) like this answer: 
[Handling onchange event in HTML.DropDownList Razor MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8973037/handling-onchange-event-in-html-dropdownlist-razor-mvc)

Comment: Viewbag and Viewdata can be unreliable.  I would recommend changing your code to pass your list through your view model and see if that helps with your issue.  See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25434762/issue-saving-edited-data-ddl-value-can-not-be-null/25436232#25436232

Comment: @MattBodily, What do you mean by unreliable? Plz can you explain a scenario. I haven't experience it or read anything what you told

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045381/render-and-select-data-from-mvc3-dropdown-list  if you look at the comments on the accepted answer they talk about viewbag there

Comment: Thanks Matt. Unfortunately, I reworked my example on .net Fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5xSAZD) and my actual code as you suggested. It still works in .net Fiddle, and still does not work in my code. Same error.

Comment: OOOOk.... my mistake. I had a code path that did not populate the property of the ViewModel. I checked @Model after the error occurred and the property is there... it's just null. Slightly misleading error, but still my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check to see if the Object/property you are specifying is null. In my case:

```
namespace MvcTest.Models
{
    public class SampleViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SelectItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and...

```
@model MvcTest.Models.SampleViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.DropDownList("SelectItems")
    </div>
}
```

SampleViewModel.SelectedItems was null...